# How to set WHERE conditions if the IF() function returns FALSE and END query if it returns TRUE in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use mysql to check if a value exists in MySQL Database. If the value exists, I want to do nothing (I don't want to fetch any data). If it does not exist, then I want to set some `where` conditions.

So this is what I have so far, but its not right. because I still get data fetched, if no `where` **condition** is set

```
SELECT *,
CASE
WHEN ( table_name.record = 'inputrecord')
THEN
    //Do nothing because it is found already
ELSE 
    // since inputrecord does not exist, we will start looking for 'id'
    ( WHERE table_name.id = '123')
END                 
FROM table_name
```

**NOTE:** In the above example, I have written `WHEN ( table_name.record = 'inputrecord')` **and not** `WHEN ( table_name.record != 'inputrecord')`. This is because I want to only continue the query if the data is not in the table.

Perhaps its better to use the `IF` **function** with the `EXISTS` **function**, but I am not sure how to do it.

Any help would be great. Right now I get errors

Comment: would you care to demonstrate please?

Comment: if your are going to do nothing when WHEN ( table_name.record = 'inputrecord') then why don't you try like "select * from table_name where table_name.record != 'inputrecord' and table_name.id = '123'"

Comment: @Dr M could I kindly ask you to re-read the question. I have mentioned in my note why I can't do that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how SQL works.

SQL always returns a collection of rows. It may be empty, sometimes rows may contain NULLs. You have to work out your conditions to filter the collection.

A generic example: say, we have a table of cars with columns (model, color, year), and you would like to find something about the cars in your table:

```
(* Find all red cars *)
select * from cars where color = 'red'

(* Find all red cars from 1985 *)
select * from cars where color = 'red' and year = 1985

(* Find all colors which exist both in 1990 and 2000 *)
select distinct color from cars A where year=1990 and exists (select 1 from cars B where year=2000 and B.color = A.color)
```

Please tell exactly what you are trying to achieve

EDIT: this should do it

```
(* select a record cars = 'Audi' only if cars = 'BMW' is not found in the whole table. otherwise. I do not want to select Audi even if it exists *)

select * from cars where model = 'Audi' and not exists (select 1 from cars where model = 'BMW')
```

here, IF there are BMWs in your table you'll get 0 rows, otherwise a list of Audis

Comment: to make it simple, I am trying to select a record cars = 'Audi' only if cars = 'BMW' is not found in the whole table's records. otherwise. I do not want to select Audi even if it exists.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the simple and detailed explanation. Really great thinking :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
SELECT *
CASE
 WHEN table_name.record = 'inputrecord' THEN 'Unspecified'
 WHEN table_name.id = '123' THEN 'table by id'
END
FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select * 
 from table_name 
 where case when table_name.record <> 'inputrecord' 
               then table_name.id = '123' 
               else 1=1 
       end
```

you can apply the given condition in your code

1. when input condition does not match then apply your filter condition.
2. when input condition match(else case )then retrieve your desired result.

Comment: Thanks let me try this :)

Comment: Thanks, but what I need is, if the ` 'inputrecord' `  is found even once in the whole table, the condition should return false and 0 rows should return. If however, the ` 'inputrecord' `  is not found at all at any time, in the table, then I'd like to apply the filters and return rows. You're solution is almost there, but it tests the ` 'inputrecord' ` for each row. so if it existed in a previous row, and it does another check for a another row, it will ignore the previous check and return a different result. Any ideas would be great to solve this